# multiple else if statements for multiple text inputs checks

Tags: java, android, if-statement

i have 5 textedits for numbers and a button. when the button is clicked the app calculates a different equation based on which field was left empty. however the app keeps crashing when i leave multiple fields empty with the error that the first double in the first if statement is invalid.

idea of the code

```
if (first field.getText().toString().equals("")) {...}
else if (second field.getText().toString().equals("")) {...}
else if (third field.getText().toString().equals("")) {...}
else if (fourth field.getText().toString().equals("")) {...}
else if (fifth.getText().toString().equals("")) {...}
else {...}
```

basically the last one should just give a toast for if it isn't any of the above (2-5 empties, 0 empties

real syntax is this:

```
    calc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText fv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pv_fv);
                EditText pv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pv_pv);
                EditText r = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pv_discountrate);
                EditText n = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pv_periods);
                EditText t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pv_years);



                if (fv.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    double r1 = Double.parseDouble(r.getText().toString());
                    double n1 = Double.parseDouble(n.getText().toString());
                    double t1 = Double.parseDouble(t.getText().toString());
                    double pv1 = Double.parseDouble(pv.getText().toString());
                    double answer1 = pv1*(Math.pow(1+(r1/n1) ,n1*t1 ));
                    answer1 = (double)(Math.round(answer1*100))/100;
                    TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pv_answer);
                    answer.setText("The Future Value of the cash flow is: "+answer1);
                }

                else if (pv.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    double fv1 = Double.parseDouble(fv.getText().toString());
                    double r1 = Double.parseDouble(r.getText().toString());
                    double n1 = Double.parseDouble(n.getText().toString());
                    double t1 = Double.parseDouble(t.getText().toString());
                    double answer1 = fv1/(Math.pow(1+(r1/n1) ,n1*t1 ));
                    answer1 = (double)(Math.round(answer1*100))/100;
                    TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pv_answer);
                    answer.setText("The Present Value of the cash flow is: "+answer1);                      
                }

                else if (r.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    double fv1 = Double.parseDouble(fv.getText().toString());
                    double pv1 = Double.parseDouble(pv.getText().toString());
                    double n1 = Double.parseDouble(n.getText().toString());
                    double t1 = Double.parseDouble(t.getText().toString());
                    double answer1 = ( (Math.pow(fv1/pv1, 1/(n1*t1) ) ) -1)*n1 ;
                    answer1 = (double)(Math.round(answer1*100))/100;
                    TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pv_answer);
                    answer.setText("The discount rate / interest rate applied is: "+answer1);
                }

                else if (t.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    double fv1 = Double.parseDouble(fv.getText().toString());
                    double pv1 = Double.parseDouble(pv.getText().toString());
                    double n1 = Double.parseDouble(n.getText().toString());
                    double r1 = Double.parseDouble(r.getText().toString());
                    double answer1 = Math.log(fv1/pv1) / (n1* Math.log(1+(r1/n1) ) ) ;
                    answer1 = (double)(Math.round(answer1*100))/100;
                    TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pv_answer);
                    answer.setText("The number of years is: "+answer1);
                }

                else if(n.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Toast errormsg = Toast.makeText(PresentValue.this, "Sorry but Number of Periods cannot be computed.", 5000);
                    errormsg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    errormsg.show();
                }

                else {
                    Toast errormsg = Toast.makeText(PresentValue.this, "You either left too many fields empty or filled all of them.", 5000);
                    errormsg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    errormsg.show();
                }

            }           
        });
```

Any idea on what's wrong with this?

Comment: What do you mean by "the first double in the first if statement"?

Comment: Your example code is invalid. Please provide real source code, so people can answer the question correctly.

Comment: You need to show the code in the first if statement, if that's what causes the error.

Comment: @martin 
done. the real syntax is in

Comment: I would say that artificial construct "else if" is dangerous/expensive from code maintainability perspective. In case someone wants to insert extra code or log statement in to else, e.g. before it was "else if", but they added "else ; if ..." would completely break existing logic...hard to spot! However when using braces it is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it. However it seems really ... stuffy. is there a way to make it more seemless?

```
//clickhandler
        calc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText fv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pv_fv);
                EditText pv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pv_pv);
                EditText r = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pv_discountrate);
                EditText n = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pv_periods);
                EditText t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pv_years);
                TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pv_answer);
                int filledfields = 0;

                if (fv.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    filledfields ++;
                }
                if (pv.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    filledfields ++;
                }
                if (r.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    filledfields ++;
                }
                if (t.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    filledfields ++;
                }
                if (n.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    filledfields ++;
                }

                if (filledfields > 1){
                    Toast errormsg = Toast.makeText(PresentValue.this, "Sorry but you left more than one field empty.", 5000);
                    errormsg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    errormsg.show();
                }

                else if (fv.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    double r1 = Double.parseDouble(r.getText().toString());
                    double n1 = Double.parseDouble(n.getText().toString());
                    double t1 = Double.parseDouble(t.getText().toString());
                    double pv1 = Double.parseDouble(pv.getText().toString());
                    double answer1 = pv1*(Math.pow(1+(r1/n1) ,n1*t1 ));
                    answer1 = (double)(Math.round(answer1*100))/100;

                    answer.setText("The Future Value of the cash flow is: "+answer1);
                }

                else if (pv.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    double fv1 = Double.parseDouble(fv.getText().toString());
                    double r1 = Double.parseDouble(r.getText().toString());
                    double n1 = Double.parseDouble(n.getText().toString());
                    double t1 = Double.parseDouble(t.getText().toString());
                    double answer1 = fv1/(Math.pow(1+(r1/n1) ,n1*t1 ));
                    answer1 = (double)(Math.round(answer1*100))/100;

                    answer.setText("The Present Value of the cash flow is: "+answer1);                      
                }

                else if (r.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    double fv1 = Double.parseDouble(fv.getText().toString());
                    double pv1 = Double.parseDouble(pv.getText().toString());
                    double n1 = Double.parseDouble(n.getText().toString());
                    double t1 = Double.parseDouble(t.getText().toString());
                    double answer1 = ( (Math.pow(fv1/pv1, 1/(n1*t1) ) ) -1)*n1 ;
                    answer1 = (double)(Math.round(answer1*100))/100;

                    answer.setText("The discount rate / interest rate applied is: "+answer1);
                }

                else if (t.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    double fv1 = Double.parseDouble(fv.getText().toString());
                    double pv1 = Double.parseDouble(pv.getText().toString());
                    double n1 = Double.parseDouble(n.getText().toString());
                    double r1 = Double.parseDouble(r.getText().toString());
                    double answer1 = Math.log(fv1/pv1) / (n1* Math.log(1+(r1/n1) ) ) ;
                    answer1 = (double)(Math.round(answer1*100))/100;

                    answer.setText("The number of years is: "+answer1);
                }

                else if(n.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Toast errormsg = Toast.makeText(PresentValue.this, "Sorry but Number of Periods cannot be computed.", 5000);
                    errormsg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    errormsg.show();
                }

                else {
                    Toast errormsg = Toast.makeText(PresentValue.this, "You either left too many fields empty or filled all of them.", 5000);
                    errormsg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    errormsg.show();
                }

            }           
        });
        //clickhandler end
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have only these five fields - the `else` statement is reachable only if none of the fields are empty.

If only one is empty, it will be caught by the relevant if statement - it works fine in this aspect.

If two ore more are empty - it will be caught only once, in the first if condition that applies - which seems not to be what you want.

If none are empty - the `else` statement will be reached, though none are empty - this is obviously what you meant for.

An alternative approach could be not using the `else if` statements, but only `if`s, and count the number of faults. If it is higher then 1 - multiple fields are empty. If it is 0 - no fields are empty. If it can be applied is of course dependent on the actual content of the blocks for each statement.

Comment: basically what I want is for it do the respective calculations when only one field is empty. When two to all are empty or none are empty then it should give the toast

Answer (score 0):

Put the names or the references to the fields into a `List` or `Set`. You can then easily retrieve the empty one you need afterwards.

And

```
if (emptyFieldSet.size() > 1) {
    toast that says "error multiples are empty"
}
```

is a lot more readable than that last `else` statement after oodles of `if`s.

Comment: You may also put all the fields in a `List` or `Set` in the first place. That way you can easily get to the right fields, and you can do cool things like `filledFieldSet = allFieldSet.removeAll(emptyFieldSet)`

Comment: i posted the real code i have up. Where would i put the fieldset?

Comment: Gotta sleep, will come back about this tomorrow, please put back the if statements in your question, otherwise many of the comments / answers don't make sense.